# How to position Image field in body content

Tags: 7, nodes, media

I have a content type that has title, body, image etc. I am displaying the Title, image with caption and body using Manage Display. But here there is no option to align (Left, Right, Center) the image. How to align the image node wise.

To meet the requirement I found INSERT module. This module is placing the image inside the body content but the caption of the image is missing.

Please help on this issue and let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Try the CSS Injector module and use CSS float property or other properties on the  .class or #id of the image field or body/description/captions.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a wysiwyg editor like ckeditor. The other option is to created a node template where content type fields are stacked like so:

- Intro copy (above image copy)
- Image
- caption
- Body

This method is not as flexible as a wysiwyg but works for consistent node presentation.